# Validation, regular expression to allow some characters

Tags: regex

I'm trying to validate a telephone number which should contain only digits with some special characters like `()` `,` `-` . I've tried the following `/^[0-9,()-]+$/` but it is showing an error. The special characters are optional, other than those special characters and digits are not allowed.

Comment: You should escape special characters like `(` or `-` using \.  So if you wish to match the character `(` you should use `\(` in your pattern.

Comment: i write expression like this
     ^[0-9,\( \) \- ]$

Comment: it is not giving error, when i copy past here in stack over flow it is not showing '\()' with back slash

Comment: Sorry.  I still don't understand.  What are you trying to paste here?  Can you paste somewhere else like pastebin.com so I can have a look at it?

Comment: this site is not accessable from my company

Comment: Bahman i am looking for the expression for telephone number that can only numaric and special characters like - and '( )' and this specail characters are optional.

Comment: would you consider some examples of inputs?

Comment: There's a better way to do this: Ideally, rather than matching the optional characters (),- you should remove them and only store the numeric portion of the phone number. Then you could validate it by matching only digits.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you take a look at [Perl's RegEx tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) and [www.regular-expressions.info](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) for a better understanding of RegEx's.
The pattern you have provided (even if syntactically corrected) is not appropriate for your case (phone numbers), as it matches strings like `78,(-34`.

The first step to write a correct RegEx is understanding the pattern you need.  For your case, you have to think about the different strings that will match as a phone number.  Some examples:

Match:

```
(500)-8764531
500-8764531
(+9821)-76787600
76787600,01
```

No match

```
(500)-876453187645318764531
500,8764531
(+9821-76787600
76787600,01)
```

The next step is to build a RegEx that matches those patterns.  After that you have to test your pattern with different boundary cases and if required do the previous steps again.

Comment: i write the expression /[0-9-\(\)].$/ it is working in Rubular but not in my code